# Conditional probability on joint pdf

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> The joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is given by:
>
> $$f(x,y) = \frac{6}{7}\left(x^2+\frac{xy}{2}\right),\quad 0 < x < 1,\quad 0 < y < 2$$
>
> Find $\;\displaystyle P  \left( \left. X > \frac{1}{4}\; \right|\; X > Y\right).$

The method I attempted for solving this solution was using the conditional probability formula $$P(B | A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$$

The resulting problem I got was $$\frac{P(X > \frac{1}{4} \cap X > Y)}{P(X > Y)}$$

I converted this to $$\frac{\int_\frac{1}{4}^1 \int_0^x\frac{6}{7}(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})\,dy dx}{\int_0^1 \int_0^x\frac{6}{7}(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})\,dydx}$$

When I solved these integrals I got $$\frac{\frac{3825}{14336}}{\frac{15}{56}} = \frac{255}{256} = 0.99$$

This answer, specifically the top integral feels off so I was wondering if I went wrong anywhere or if the method I used is wrong entirely. Thanks!

Comment: I think your [denominator might be incorrect](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BIntegrate%5B6%2F7*(x%5E2%2Bx*y%2F2),%7By,0,x%7D%5D,%7Bx,0,1%7D%5D).

Comment: Yes, I did put the wrong denominator in, but the correct one still leaves me concerned with the answer. Is there any chance you see an issue with the numerator?

Comment: Assuming the supports $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 2$ are correctly specified, [it looks good to me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BIntegrate%5B6%2F7*(x%5E2%2Bx*y%2F2),%7By,0,x%7D%5D,%7Bx,1%2F4,1%7D%5D).

Comment: *Mathematica* agrees with 255/256:`d = ProbabilityDistribution[(6/7) (x^2 + x y/2), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]; Probability[x > 1/4 \[Conditioned] x > y, {x, y} \[Distributed] d]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to integrate over $\{1/4<x<1, 0<y<x\}$ and $\{0<x<1, 0<y<x\}$, as you have.

$$\mathsf P(X>1/4\mid X>Y)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(1/4<X<1,0<Y<X)}{\mathsf P(0<X<1,0<Y<X)}$$

Now $\int_0^x (x^2+xy/2)\mathsf d y=5x^3/4$, and $\int_z^1 x^3\mathsf d x=(1-z^4)/4$, so $$\mathsf P(X>1/4\mid X>Y)=\dfrac{(1-1/4^4)}{(1-0^4)}=\dfrac{255}{256}$$

So everything checks out okay.